# quick pattern explain

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I want this string:

```
value="1,'goahead'" your='56' so='"<br />"'
```

I want php regex to return result array as following :

```
value="1,'goahead'"
your='56'
so='"<br />"'
```

I tried this regex :

```
preg_match_all("#([\d\w_]+)\s*=\s*(\"|')([^'\"]*)(\"|')*#isx")
```

but it failed to fetch this value: `value="1,'goahead'"`

I think that it's because of single quotation inside the value. Please help me with improved pattern.

Comment: What's wrong with `explode(" ",$str)`?

Comment: The only issue with `explode(" ",$str)` is that it will pick up on the space in `'"<br />"'`.

Comment: yes , but what happened when a space found value="1,'goahead' " ?

Comment: @Jason4Ever Ah, well spotted. I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/DOMDocument):

If your input is a complete tag...

```
<p value="1,'goahead'" your='56' so='"<br />"'>
```

...then you can do this:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str);
foreach ($DOM->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->attributes as $attr) {
  $attributes[$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
}
```

This gives you the array you're looking for:

```
Array
(
    [value] => 1,'goahead'
    [your] => 56
    [so] => "<br />"
)
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/TIIZ2

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off with this regex:

```
/(\w+)\s*=\s*(["'])(.*?)\2/
```

This will give the attribute name in the first subpattern, the type of quote used in the second, and the attribute value in the third.

Of particular importance are the `.*?`, which matches lazily (ie. the least possible) and the `\2` which matches the second subpattern (in this case, the quote used). This does not allow for escaping with `\"` or `\'`, though. That's be a bit more involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to ask how you'd end up to do this and why, anyway, this might help you:

`if (preg_match('%(value="\d+,(\s+)?\'[a-z]+\'"(\s+)?)?(your=\'\d+\'(\s+)?)?(so=\'"<br(\s+)?\/>"\')?%six', $subject, $matches)) { }`